# Ruby on Rails and jQuery not working locally but on heroku is fine

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, local

I got an weird problem! I'm trying to make a site in Rails, I got some documentation but I can't figure this one out. I'm using a jQuery plug-in to alter my scrollbars inside an div as you can see on this website,

http://dontkeepmewaiting.heroku.com/home/index

I made a screenshot of the only difference I could find between the version on Heroku and the localhost version, it's pretty big (1900x1200)

http://no-illusions.nl/random/jquery_rails.png

as you can see all the files are the same (I checked them) the only thing that's different is the order but that can't be it right?

Maybe Heroku has an gem install which I don't?

Comment: post layout with jquery plugin, make it easy for people to see the question without having to visit another site

Comment: Why do you have a `jQuery.js` and a `jQuery.min.js` and which one is the proper version of jquery?

Comment: Thanks for the fast respons. Well the problem is simple, my site on localhost does not load or read the jQuery well so it does not work but on the heroku site it works fine. So I am wondering what the difference is. The only difference I could find was the order at which the files were loaded.

@Josiah, I did not notice that yet, there's an 1.5 and an 1.6 file in there. I'll correct that.

Comment: Cheers Josiah, what an stupid mistake! I remove the 1.5 v of jQuery from the folder and it's working fine now. I think I installed it when I did the gem install rails command.

Comment: post your `application.html.erb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the javascript files

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but it kind of lacks some information (for me). Where should I check the permission? I'm running it localy on an win7 installation.

Comment: Haven't used Windows in awhile but I'll give it a short. Right click on the file, select Properties, look for permissions.